# Content export in ektron

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, ektron

I am new to Ektron & using its 8.6.0 version, I want to create an widget which Import content of selected folder/form in Xliff/XML format (working same as EKtron provide but need to implement in custom widget using code, not in browser), I receive mail from support they tell that "There is a set of API’s that allows you to connect to the language export feature." but I am unable to find any API. Is anyone can help me for this.

I have use following approach but not get any result.

```
Localization temp = new Localization();
temp.StartExportContentForTranslation("1136,5012,5006", "2057,1031,1041");
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a feature in the workarea that you want to emulate, just look at the workarea code. In `Workarea\controls\content\localization_uc.ascx.cs`,  It says

```
protected Ektron.Cms.LocalizationAPI m_objLocalizationApi = new Ektron.Cms.LocalizationAPI();
protected Ektron.Cms.BusinessObjects.Localization.L10nManager localizationManager = null;
```

And then calls `StartExportContentForTranslation`

Comment: I have already use these two lines before my code but not get result. Please suggest some more.