# Creating XLIFF file of a Content in Ektron

Tags: ektron, xliff

I am working in Ektron 8.6.

I am creating a Custom widget for the creation of XLIFF file for a corresponding content in workarea by passing it's Content ID.
I have referred the files in the workarea folder of my ektron website to get the Ektron API's to emulate this functionality(as this is already handled by ektron).I got some inputs form the following file:Workarea\controls\content\localization_uc.ascx.cs and tried the following code:

```
Localization temp = new Localization();
temp.StartExportContentForTranslation("36,12,50", "1031,1041");
```

I also tried:

```
            Ektron.Cms.ContentAPI m_refContentApi = new Ektron.Cms.ContentAPI();
            Ektron.Cms.BusinessObjects.Localization.L10nManager localizationManager = null;
            localizationManager = new    Ektron.Cms.BusinessObjects.Localization.L10nManager(m_refContentApi.RequestInformationRef);
            localizationManager.StartExportContentForTranslation("30,35", "1078,1052");
            localizationManager.StartImportTranslation();
```

But this code doesn't seems to work.
What i am i doing wrong here?
I found another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330302/content-export-in-ektron) regarding the same issue.But that loop also is not having a solution to the issue.
Can someone help me in fixing this issue?